# Mute/unmute video with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullscreen.js to display multiple slides containing video on each slide. I would like to use the afterSlideLoad event to do the following:

1. Mute the previous slide video
2. Unmute the video in the 'active' slide

The furthest I have gotten is unmuting the video on slide2 load, however it stays unmuted after leaving the slide to the next video.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: true,
            fitToSection: true,
            controlArrows: false,
            afterRender: function(){
                //playing the video
                $('video').get(0).play();
            },
            afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
                $('#myVideo').prop('muted', false)
            }, 
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">

        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            <video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide2">
            <video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo2">
                <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks), i think you can use the `onLeave()` callback:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        // mute video from last slide
        $('video').eq(index-1)[0].muted = true;
        // unmute video from current slide
        $('video').eq(nextIndex-1)[0].muted = false;
    },
});
```

Interestingly the index starts at 1, so you'd have to use `index-1`.